# Custom permalink - append taxonomy name and term name at the end of permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have

```
custom post type -> resources
custom taxonomy  -> resources_type
```

I want custom permalinks where category base will be appended at the end instead of front

For example:  I add a new resource with **title "First resource"** and assign **term as type1**

**What I get** -  http://example.com/resources/resources-type/type1/first-resource

***What i want*** - http://example.com/resources/first-resource/resources-type/type1

I am using the following argument code in register post type :

```
'rewrite' => array("slug" => "/resources/resources-type/%resources_type%"),
```

And then using following code to replace  the "%resources_type%"  in above code

```
function wpa_course_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
  $post = get_post($id);  
  if ( is_object( $post ) ){
      $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'resources_type' );
      if( $terms ){
        return str_replace( '%resources_type%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
      }
  }
  return $post_link;  
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_course_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the following permalink structure by simply overriding (without having to remove) the default one (you specified) for the `resources` post type:

```
/resources/%resources%/resources-type/%resources_type% <- preferred
/resources/resources-type/%resources_type%/%resources% <- default
```

And you can override it via [`add_permastruct()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_permastruct/) — first, register the post type without specifying the `rewrite` parameter which means the rewrite defaults to `true`/enabled and that the slug would be `resources` (i.e. the *post type key or slug*):

```
register_post_type( 'resources', array(
    'label' => 'Resources',
    'public' => true,
    // no need to set the 'rewrite' arg
    ...
) );
```

Then right after that, override the permalink structure like so:

```
add_permastruct( 'resources', '/resources/%resources%/resources-type/%resources_type%' );
```

where the format is — the important part is the `{POST TYPE KEY}`, which in your case is `resources`:

```
add_permastruct( '{POST TYPE KEY}', '{PERMALINK STRUCTURE}' );
```

*(Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules — just visit the permalink settings page.)*

### How to disable `/resources/%resources%`

`/resources/%resources%` (i.e. `/{POST TYPE KEY}/%{POST TYPE KEY}%`) is *automatically* added if `%{POST TYPE KEY}%` is found in the permalink structure. You can remove it like so:

```
add_filter( 'resources_rewrite_rules', 'filter_resources_rewrite_rules' );
function filter_resources_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $pattern = 'resources/([^/]+)/resources-type/';
    $p_length = strlen( $pattern );

    foreach ( $rules as $regex => $query ) {
        if ( $pattern !== substr( $regex, 0, $p_length ) ) {
            unset( $rules[ $regex ] );
        }
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

*If the post type is hierarchical, then the `$pattern` would be `resources/(.+?)/resources-type/`.*

And if you'd like to use the above code/function with another post type, you basically only need to replace the text "*resources*" with the proper post type *key*.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/permastructname_rewrite_rules/ for more details on that filter.

Comment: Hi there Thanks for the solution .. It does resolve the issue .. and i get permalink like '/resources/%resources%/resources-type/%resources_type%'     but issue is    there is also another permalink which is working  i,e '/resources/%resources%/    .. I don't want that second permalink at all

Comment: Ok, I'll update the answer later.

Comment: Hi Sally , thanks for helping out . Looking forward for your update

Comment: Please check the updated answer and let me know how it goes.

Comment: How is it, @terminator? If you've already found a solution, do share it with us. But I appreciate it if you could upvote the answer since (I believe that) it did help you. :)

Comment: It worked awesome, upvoted plus awarded the bounty .. Thanks a lot friend

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad it worked well. :)